# Can I combine two bundles together in a specific order, like concatenate both bundles and produce one bundle for them?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

Basically I have a bundle that I use quite often plus other js files in other views, so can I just add these files, while preserving their order, to the existing bundle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked it up everywhere but cannot find a way to combine two bundles together, you can only bundle files.